# GasLimit check failed for header -1 when mining in private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

On a machine with `geth` and `geth --testnet` running I would like to creat a private chain as well.

I have created a private chain with the following `genesis.json`

```
{
    "name": "hackathon",
    "engine": {
        "Ethash": {
            "params": {
                "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x0400",
                "minimumDifficulty": "0x400",
                "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x0800",
                "durationLimit": "0x0a",
                "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
                "registrar": "",
                "frontierCompatibilityModeLimit": "0x0"
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "accountStartNonce": "0x0100000",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID" : "0x3942"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "ethereum": {
                "nonce": "0x0000000000003942",
                "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x400",
        "timestamp": "0x00",
        "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "extraData": "0x0",
        "gasLimit": "0x4c4b40",
        "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "alloc": {}
    },
    "nodes": [],
    "accounts": {}
}
```

I then initialized the chain with `geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/hackathon init genesis.json`

and get the success message:

```
I1112 15:06:15.214815 ethdb/database.go:83] Alloted 16MB cache and 16 file handles to /home/mroon/.ethereum/hackathon/chaindata
I1112 15:06:15.221926 cmd/geth/main.go:299] successfully wrote genesis block and/or chain rule set: 78dec18c6d7da925bbe773c315653cdc70f6444ed6c1de9ac30bdb36cff74c3b
```

I then run `geth`, create an account and start the miner with `miner.start()`

This is how geth is started:

```
geth --datadir ~/.ethereum/hackathon --networkid 42 --port 30304 console 2>>hackathon-geth.log
```

and this is the error message in the log after after the miner starts:

```
I1112 15:07:26.044185 eth/backend.go:454] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG ON (ethash dir: /home/mroon/.ethash)
I1112 15:07:26.044308 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir: /home/mroon/.ethash)
I1112 15:07:26.044689 miner/miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=8 TOT=9)
I1112 15:07:26.045255 ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 0 (size 1073739904) (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
I1112 15:07:26.632381 ethash.go:276] Done generating DAG for epoch 0, it took 587.138328ms
I1112 15:07:27.119837 miner/worker.go:288] Invalid header on mined block: GasLimit check failed for header -1 (1 > 0)
```

the first look OK but then there is this GasLimit thing.